# How to make a div fade on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I currently have span that displays over an image on hover, however I want to use a bit of javascript or css transitions to make this div fade in to about 0.8 opacity on hover then back to 0 when the mouse is not hovering.

Here is an example of how I have it setup so far, now all thats needed is the fade and 0.8 opacity:

[How its setup - Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Christophe/2RN6E/4/)

Im sure there is a simple bit of code that someone has to do this

Help is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So... here's the CSS3 / HTML5-way to do this. This won't work in IE though: it will fall back on the regular, immediate way (so it does work, it just isn't as smooth as it is in the real browsers).

```
div.yourDiv {
    -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -moz-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -o-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
}

div.yourDiv:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Since CSS3-transitions are using hardware-accerelation, this really is very smooth! Besides that, you don't even need any Javascript or jQuery for this =)!

Comment: Yeah man I tried this before I came to stackoverflow because I love using the CSS Transitions, its just when I add the transition to the span that is unhidden on hover. It doesnt fade in?

Comment: Your a genius. Best solution :D Thank you. It was because of the display:none. That was causing the issue. Im using opacity 0 now haha

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class, unless you need to support IE6:

```
.image-hover:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}

* html .image-hover:hover { /* For IE7 and higher */
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

That won't *fade* to 80%, though, it'll just go there immediately. To do that, you can use jQuery's [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) and [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) functions (*edit*: or [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/), which is just a convenience wrapper for `animate` on `opacity` as shown below):

```
$(".image-hover").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "0.8"});
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"});
    }
);
```

It's not clear from your question what the text in the span is supposed to be doing, but those are the tools to get you started.

[Here's an updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RN6E/10/) showing the animation; I've used 0.6 rather than 0.8 just so it's more obvious.

Comment: Why not use `fadeTo` instead of `animate`? =)

Comment: @Tomas: No particular reason, `animate` was the tool that came to my fingers as I was answering. :-) `fadeTo` just calls `animate`, though it does check first to make sure the element is showing.

Comment: To the person who tried to edit `opacity: "1"` to `opacity: "0"` (sorry, didn't clock the name before rejecting it): No, it should be `"1"` when we un-hover, to bring the div back to full display.

Answer (score 1):

```
.classa
{
opacity:0.8;
}
```

you can `addClass` and `removeClass` like

```
$("div.image-hover").hover(
function(){
//fadein
$(this).addClass("classa");
},
function(){
//fadeout
    $(this).removeClass("classa");
}
);
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2RN6E/8/

**EDITED after the comment below**

you can use [**`fadeTo`**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

```
$("div.image-hover").hover(
function(){
//fadein
$(this).fadeTo( "2000", "0.8");
},
function(){
//fadeout
    $(this).fadeTo( "2000","1");
}
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2RN6E/14/
    );

Comment: He said *fade*, rather than immediately dimming without fade.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
function fadein() {
    $('.desc').animate({
        opacity: 0.8,

    }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    })

}

function fadeout() {
    $('.desc').animate({
        opacity: 0,

    }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    })

}

$('.image-hover').hover(fadein, fadeout);
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/2RN6E/9/

Comment: Hey man this works sweet but it keeps looping for some reason when im hovering on the link, i just need it to stop doing this. Hmmmmm??

Answer (score 0):

This code retains the block display for the description element: http://jsfiddle.net/2RN6E/11/

It just uses the animate function of jQuery:

```
$(".image-hover").hover(function() {
    $(".desc").animate({opacity: '0.75'},'slow');
}, function() {
    $(".desc").animate({opacity: '0'},'slow');   
});
```